# Use of 'both' and verb-subject agreement

Tags: grammar

> "I have heard two immediate reactions to it and **both connotes** sadness, which are certainly well founded."

I am concerned about the use of 'both' as singular and of verb-subject agreement.

Also: Do I need to use the preposition 'of', as in, "I have heard OF two..."

Comment: “Both” requires plural agreement.

Comment: Are you asking if *both reactions* is singular?

Comment: Thank you, Lawrence.  I like the way you put the question, Yosef.  That's clever.